# How to Invert a White image to Black using SVG Filters?

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

Is there a way to invert a white image to black using SVG filters?

In CSS Filter, we do `-webkit-filter:invert(1);` which does not work in IE10. I am applying SVG filters as fallback. Any one can help?

Comment: acutally IE has a filter for invert, since version 4.0. checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533008(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can invert using an SVG Filter:

```
<feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="-1 0 0 0 1 
                                                              0 -1 0 0 1 
                                                              0 0 -1 0 1
                                                              0 0 0 1 0"/>
```

For more detail see the docs on [feColorMatrix at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feColorMatrix)

Comment: For me, this did not work, until I applied the filter in Inkscape, which created a whole bunch of chained filters (available upon request).

Comment: I did not give you the entire filter code - just the core primitive Look up the docs I link to see how to do this.