# How to use an black image as svg mask?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

[the first mask image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5BQj.png)

[the second mask image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpxWD.png)

**why not use the first mask image?**

```
<svg width='200' height='200' baseProfile='full' version='1.2'>
  <defs>
    <mask id='svg_mask' maskUnits='userSpaceOnUse' maskContentUnits='userSpaceOnUse' transform='scale(1)'>
      <image  width='200' height='200'
             xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXnMG.png' />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image mask='url(#svg_mask)' width='200' height='200' y='0' x='0'
         xlink:href='http://static.timeface.cn/times/0f62b706f726d823393290ef1ee60944.jpg' />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to use an image as a mask it's the white areas that contributes. So, if you've a black/transparent image you get no effect.
However, we *can* transform the image before we try to use it as a filter. If we use a `feColorMatrix`, we can define a matrix which will invert colours for us. By applying this filter directly to the image and then using the (transformed) image as a mask, we can achieve a rounded maksing.

I've also added the `xmlns` attribute to the root node and removed the `xlink:` namespace prefixes.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width='200' height='200' baseProfile='full' version='1.2'>
  <defs>
 <filter id='negative'><feColorMatrix values='-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0'/></filter>
 
    <mask id='svg_mask' maskUnits='userSpaceOnUse' maskContentUnits='userSpaceOnUse' transform='scale(1)'>
      <image  filter='url(#negative)' width='200' height='200' href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5BQj.png' />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image mask='url(#svg_mask)' width='200' height='200' y='0' x='0' href='http://static.timeface.cn/times/0f62b706f726d823393290ef1ee60944.jpg' />
</svg>
```

Credits to https://gist.github.com/brysongilbert/6062276 for the filter code.

Another question which deals with SVG color inversion: [How to Invert a White image to Black using SVG Filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873715/how-to-invert-a-white-image-to-black-using-svg-filters)